# Question, is possible to add this The WiringPi and The StepperMotor library to Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, wiringpi

I want to make in QT, Gui for control stepper motor using the Raspberry Pi.(Adress from where i took library)

https://crish4cks.net/a-simple-c-library-to-drive-a-stepper-motor-using-the-raspberry-pi/.
Question, is possible to add this The WiringPi and The StepperMotor library to Qt?
When i try with steps from this page not works.
https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html

Funfact.. I try first time make this also in Virtual_box(Ubuntu) but in terminal but also was some problem with instal library for the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What part did not work? Did you look at your .pro file?

Comment: Can say me what is this ? With Qt i working first time

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/771809614349991986/939093535184011314/unknown.png

Comment: The error is a network problem with the site you are trying to download source code from.